# How can I make a counter trigger that updates a different table?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

Basicly what I want to do is create a trigger which is updates the number of workers in the city I inserted the new worker in but so far I have no idea how could I make that.

This is the code so far but it doesn't works but I think it makes sense what I meant to do.

```
Create or replace trigger Worker_insert
After insert
on worker

begin
   update cities Set workers_count=workers_count+1 
   where cities.name=worker.city;    
    
end;
```

Comment: There is no join to your alias ```worker``` on ```worker.city```

Comment: I would highly recommend *NOT* to do that.  Disaster waiting to happen.  just do a select count(*) on the table or create a view over the cities table that does that.

Answer (score 2):

You almost certainly don't want to do this.  It rarely makes sense to denormalize data.  Storing totals in a separate table that you maintain with triggers is likely to cause you a whole lot of grief over time.  It opens you up to mutating table errors in the future when you create a future trigger on `cities` for some reason, it is a pain to correctly handle every possible case (you'd need to handle the case where you delete a worker or update a worker's city, for example).  That's particularly true when it is a statistic like the number of workers in a city which is unlikely to be queried frequently and is unlikely to need to be particularly accurate so the potential benefit to denormalization is minimal.  It would almost always make more sense to create a view that performs the calculation for you if you want a real-time result or a materialized view that refreshes nightly if you're happy with an approximate result.

However, if you really want to denormalize, you'd do something like this (you'd need to handle the obvious `delete` and `update` cases)

```
Create or replace trigger Worker_insert
  After insert
  on worker
  for each row
begin
   update cities 
      Set workers_count = nvl(workers_count,0)+1 
    where cities.name=:new.city;    
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not want a trigger for this; you want to use a `VIEW`:

```sql
CREATE VIEW city_workers ( city_name, workers_count ) AS
SELECT c.name,
       COUNT(w.id)
FROM   cities c
       LEFT OUTER JOIN worker w
       ON ( c.name = w.city )
GROUP BY c.name
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4431250e87a536b19d00ea9e05405e69)*